# ¿como puedo hacer un programa en python que abra programas en python?

Tags: python

necesito hacer un programa .py que abra otro programa en .py el cual se encuentre en la misma carpeta, como puedo hacerlo ?, gracias de antemano :D

Comment: `exec(open('file.py').read())`?

Comment: Por "abrir" un programa ¿quieres decir ejecutar, o leer el código?

Comment: Siempre puedes usar `subprocess`, pero ¿Cuál es la razón de querer ejecutar el script desde otro script? Puedes importar el módulo y ejecutar lo que quieras en ese mismo hilo o en otro hilo o usar multiprocessing, ...